# Lightbox 2 How to Open Lightbox in Separate Div or Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have a html page with thumbnails that open up a lightbox using Lightbox 2. It's working, except the lightbox overlays the entire page and covers the thumbnails. How can I get the lightbox to appear in a separate div so that the thumbs aren't covered? It's probably very simple but for some reason it's not working for me. Here's my code.

```
    <div id="lightbox_target">Would like lightbox to open here</div>
    <div class="sc_menu">

    <ul class="sc_menu">
          <li><a href="aitwilight.jpg" target="lightbox_target" data-lightbox="new work"   data-title='<I>Twilight, </I> oil on canvas 36"x 36" 2013 (Private Collection)'><img src="aitwilight.jpg" height="75" width="75"  title="Twilight" alt="Twilight" /></a></li>
<!--etc-->
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to make a gallery functionality? might be easier to look for another plugin than changing it to fit since even if you remove the overlay it will still require 2 clicks to change picture I guess (1 to close 1 to reopen)

Comment: Lightbox may not be the best solution to this problem. I would create my own html/css for the output and use a few lines of jQuery to populate `#lightbox_target` or child elements.

Comment: Ok, I do have some code to make a gallery. I just kind of like lightbox and I have trouble having images of different sizes overlaying each other whenever I have a gallery or slideshow. Thanks.